# Billing Plan with Addons

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk, recurring-billing

I offer services with recurring billing.
Therefore I'd like to use paypal rest API and billing plans/agreements.

The problem I'm currently facing is that I'd like to offer addons to regular services.

So it could be service 1 + addon 1, service 1 + addon 2, service 1 + addon 3, etc.

To start a billing agreement I first need a billing plan, but what's the best way to handle it with addons as the price constantly changes?

Create new billing plans on the fly when placing an order?
Create billing plans for all possible add on combinations?
Maybe it's possible to assign multiple billing plans to one billing agreement?
Maybe something else?

Answer (score 1):

A billing agreement does not accept multiple plan IDs. As for 'best' way, that is subjective.

Creating a plan based off of what the customer is purchasing and then creating the billing agreement

and

Preemptively creating a billing plan for each combination and referencing the plan ID in the billing agreement

Both of these will work fine, just will be different integration methodologies.

Comment: Is there a limit to how many different billing plans a paypal account can have? Would you see any flaw in creating a billing agreement upon user purchase if he wants addons? Is it possible to create a billing plan so its state is active instantly after creation?